# How to find the database exist or not with Jaydata Context

Tags: jaydata

I am working on an application with jaydata as ORM and angularjs as middle layer : working with jaydata how can i find with context that whether the DB has already benn created or its the first time it is been created by the code ..>???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this check only if you verify the number of the records in a specific table that normaly contains data.